# Acer Aspire S3 or Asus Zenbook Ultrabook for running Linux (Ubuntu / Debian)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, laptop

I'm curious if anyone has had success with running Ubuntu or Debian on the latest Ultrabooks.  Specifically, the Acer Aspire s3 or the Asus Zenbook?

I have had an Asus UL30a since they came out, but since the latest dist-upgrade landed linux-3 on my system, suspend/resume when on battery just dies.  Works fine when plugged in so I assume it's trying to "Hibernate" when on battery.

Any experiences appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have either of those, but I did a quick search.
I couldn't find much on the Zenbook, but the S3 had a review here:

http://www.linlap.com/wiki/acer+aspire+s3

Basically, The only problems are:
1) Fan 
2) Bluetooth
3) Screen Brightness

Everything but the Bluetooth seems to have a work-around as well.

I say go for it. Good luck!